# Getting bad request error when posting file to server using python requests library

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

I am getting http code 400 (bad request) when I am trying to post a file to server using python requests library.

Corresponding `curl` request which is successful:

```sh
curl -X POST -i https://de.api.labs.sophos.com/analysis/file/static/v1 \
-H 'Authorization: auth_string' \
-H 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data' \
-F "file=@filename"
```

API documentation: https://api.labs.sophos.com/doc/analysis/file/static.html

Can someone help me out what I might be doing wrong?
My code so far:

```py
import requests

url = "https://de.api.labs.sophos.com/analysis/file/static/v1"
headers = {'content-type': 'multipart/form-data', 'Authorization': authorization}

with open(filepath, 'rb') as f:      
    files = {'file': f}  # Even tried {'file': f.read()}
    r = requests.post(url, files=files, headers=headers)
    if r.status_code in [200, 202]:
        return r.json()
    else:
        return r
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### TL;DR

Try to do it this way:

```py
import requests

url = "https://de.api.labs.sophos.com/analysis/file/static/v1"
headers = {'Authorization': authorization}  # no Content-Type here

r = requests.post(url, headers=headers, files={"file": open(filepath, "rb")})
print(r.status_code, r.text)
```

#### Why

You shouldn't set `Content-Type` header manually when [posting files](https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#post-a-multipart-encoded-file) with `requests`.

There are 2 reasons why:

- `requests` will set `Content-Type` to `multipart/form-data` implicitly before making an actual HTTP request (as it does for `Content-Length` for example)
- When using `Content-Type: multipart/form-data` you should specify a [boundary](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type#Directives) as well. If no boundary is set, server will not be able to read data from request body correctly. So **boundary is a required part** of `Content-Type` header, if you use `multipart/form-data`.

---

In your example you haven't set boundary for the request. The fact is that `requests` **does not set it for you** if you override `Content-Type` header (which you do). And then server is not able to read your file in request body. Therefore, it returns you `400 Bad Request`.

You can check it by typing `print(r.request.headers["Content-Type"])` after you've made your request. It will output this:

```
multipart/form-data
```

, but it must look like this instead:

```
multipart/form-data; boundary=6387a52fb4d1465310a2b63b2d1c6e70
```

---

On the other hand, `curl` **adds boundary implicitly**, so you everything is fine and you receive `200 OK`.

You can check it as well:

```sh
curl -H 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data' -F "file=@123.txt" -v http://httpbin.org/post
```

Which outputs:

```
* Connected to httpbin.org (34.230.136.58) port 80 (#0)
> POST /post HTTP/1.1
> Host: httpbin.org
> User-Agent: curl/7.47.0
> Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=------------------------d257f5f4377a3997
...
```

Comment: Wow !!! It worked without content-type. Thank You Ivan, for such a detailed answer :)